# What is the equivalent of this Cipher.encrypt() function in PHP

Tags: php, security, encryption, cryptography, cbc-mode

A client has sent me an encrypted message using the Cipher.encrypt()function (from some programming language unknown to me) as detailed below :

```
    var key : String = "I deleted the key intentionally";
    var encodedKey : Bytes = Encoding.toBase64(new Bytes(key, "UTF8"));

    var salt : String = "263BC60258FF4876";

    var message : String = "1234567891234567";

    var encryptAlgorithm : String = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";

    var encryptedMessage : Cipher = new Cipher();
    encryptedMessage = encryptedMessage.encrypt(message, encodedKey, encryptAlgorithm, salt, 1);
```

I need to decrypt the message in order to extract data from it using PHP.
I have tried to use the php function mcrypt_decrypt :

```
string mcrypt_decrypt ( string $cipher , string $key , string $data , string $mode [, string $iv ] )
```

But I couldn't decrypt the message since the 2 functions appear to have different arguments.

So does anyone have any suggestion regarding how to decrypt the message using PHP?

Comment: Someone needs to detect that language first.

Comment: Look like the langauge is [ActionScript](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/variables.html)

Comment: It is best not to use mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt had many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003.. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption), it is being maintained and is correct.

Comment: Ask the client what the language is.

Answer (score 0):

The following line does not make sense, it seems to be "backwards".

```
var encodedKey : Bytes = Encoding.toBase64(new Bytes(key, "UTF8"));
```

Assuming the key was Base64 encoded(which is reasonable) one would expect to decode it into a byte array and `Encoding.toBase64` seems incorrect. But this is a quest since the language is unknown, ask the client what the language is.

Next it appears that the message was encrypted with PKCS#5 padding and mcrypt does not support that. There are a couple of solutions: 1. Remove the padding in your PHP code. 2. Use a better library that does support PKCS#5 padding such as [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption).

The valuable `salt` is probably the IV (Initialization Vector) poorly named.